# Show Click of a Button

Tags: charts, google-visualization

i am using Google Visulization Charts (donut Charts )

The Chart has got tool Tips

On CLick of  a Button can we show tool tips dynamically ??

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {
    packages: ["corechart"]
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Task');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Hours per Day');
    data.addRows([
        ['A', roundNumber(11 * Math.random(), 2)],
        ['B', roundNumber(2 * Math.random(), 2)],
        ['C', roundNumber(2 * Math.random(), 2)],
        ['D', roundNumber(2 * Math.random(), 2)],
        ['E', roundNumber(7 * Math.random(), 2)]
        ]);
    var options = {
        width: 450,
        height: 300,
        colors: ['#ECD078','#ccc','#C02942','#542437','#53777A'],
        legend: {position:'none'},
        pieHole: 0.4,
        animation: {duration:800,easing:'in'}
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}

function roundNumber(num, dec) {
    var result = Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, dec)) / Math.pow(10, dec);
    return result;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){
   alert('show tool tips')
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kcjr90sx/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, need to use the latest version of google charts,
the `jsapi` loader is outdated, and should no longer be used.

use instead --> `<script src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>`

this will only change the `load` statement.
see following snippet and [update library loader code](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#update-library-loader-code) for more info.

---

next, we can use the following option to allow tooltips to be shown when a slice is selected...

```
tooltip: {
  trigger: 'both'
}
```

and we can use the following option to select multiple slices...

```
selectionMode: 'multiple',
```

then, when we click the button, we select the slices, which displays the tooltips.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Task');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Hours per Day');
  data.addRows([
    ['A', roundNumber(11 * Math.random(), 2)],
    ['B', roundNumber(2 * Math.random(), 2)],
    ['C', roundNumber(2 * Math.random(), 2)],
    ['D', roundNumber(2 * Math.random(), 2)],
    ['E', roundNumber(7 * Math.random(), 2)]
  ]);
  var options = {
    width: 450,
    height: 300,
    colors: ['#ECD078','#ccc','#C02942','#542437','#53777A'],
    legend: {position:'none'},
    pieHole: 0.4,
    animation: {duration:800,easing:'in'},
    selectionMode: 'multiple',
    tooltip: {
      trigger: 'both'
    }
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    $("#button").click(function(){
      var selection = [];
      $.each(new Array(data.getNumberOfRows()), function (rowIndex) {
        if (data.getValue(rowIndex, 1) > 0) {
          selection.push({row: rowIndex});
        }
      });
      chart.setSelection(selection);
    });
  });
  chart.draw(data, options);
});

function roundNumber(num, dec) {
  var result = Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, dec)) / Math.pow(10, dec);
  return result;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>
<div id="button" data-role="button">Show Tool Tips</div>
<div id='chart_div'></div>
```

note: you should also wait for the chart's `'ready'` event,
before assigning the button click event.
otherwise, an error will be thrown.

Comment: Thanks a lot @WhiteHat , it helped a lot . before setting the setSelection , can we check the row  0 , row 1 ... etc , because if its zero i dont want to set ToolTip